# analyzed BST height balanced

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I was looking at the code for checking if a BST is height balanced and have a question in understanding the following code.

```
def is_balanced(cur_node) :
        if (not cur_node) :
            height = 0
            return True, height

        is_left_balanced, left_height = TreeNode.is_balanced(cur_node.left)
        is_right_balanced, right_height = TreeNode.is_balanced(cur_node.right)

        #To get the height of the current node, we find the maximum of the  
        #left subtree height and the right subtree height and add 1 to it
        height = max(left_height, right_height) + 1

        if (not is_left_balanced or not is_right_balanced):
            return False, height

        #If the difference between height of left subtree and height of
        #right subtree is more than 1, then the tree is unbalanced
        if (abs(left_height - right_height) > 1):
            return False, height

        return True, height
```

I was wondering, why do we need

```
height = max(left_height, right_height) + 1
```

How exactly does finding the max help us?

Thank you

Comment: If `left_height` is the height of a tree rooted at left child, and `right_height` is the height of a tree rooted at right child, then the height of a tree at current node is height of the higher subtree plus one (for the current node). Try drawing an asymmetric tree and determining its height "by hand".

Comment: the height of the the tree is the greater of the height of the left & right trees, plus 1 for the current node.